Code for a load cycler seems to be stuck
I am trying to make a battery load cycler to charge and discharge a battery repeatedly for a certain amount of cycles and here is my code:
bool in_charge_mode;
int cycles = 0;
float cutoffvoltage = 2.0f;

float get_batt_voltage() {
    return analogRead(A1) * 5.0f / 1023.0f;
}

void set_charge_mode() {
    in_charge_mode = true; // remember state
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH); //start charge
    digitalWrite(12, LOW); //stop discharging to load
}

void set_discharge_mode() {
    in_charge_mode = false;
    digitalWrite(13, LOW); //stop charge
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH); //discharge to load
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(12, OUTPUT); //Connected to relay 1 which is relay for load
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT); //Connected to relay 2 which is relay for charger
    // Check initial voltage
    float vbat = get_batt_voltage();
    if (vbat < cutoffvoltage) {
        // battery is below the cutoff voltage, we need to start charging
        set_charge_mode();
    } else {
        // we can discharge if above cutoff voltage
        set_discharge_mode();
    }
}

void loop() {
    if (cycles >= 500) {
        Serial.println("Refusing to do anything, number of cycles too high");
        set_charge_mode(); // to disconnect from load or something
        return;
    }

    float vbat = get_batt_voltage();
    Serial.println("Battery voltage: " + String(vbat) + " is charging: " + String(in_charge_mode));
    if (in_charge_mode) {
        if (vbat > 4.2f) {
            // we're done charging! increase cycle counter
            cycles++; // technically, this is the number of "charge ups complete"
            Serial.println("BATTERY CHARGED SUFFICIENTLY. Discharging again.");
            set_discharge_mode();
        } else {
            Serial.println("Still charging up the battery, waiting..");
        }
    } else {
        // in discharge mode
        if (vbat < cutoffvoltage) {
            // battery has sunk below our cutoff voltage, we need to charge up again
            Serial.println("BATTERY DISCHARGED. Charging up again.");
            set_charge_mode();
        } else {
            Serial.println("Still dicharging the battery, waiting..");
        }
    }
    delay(1000); // check again in one second
}

however the serial monitor keeps repeating this:
Battery voltage: 4.18 is charging: 0
Still dicharging the battery, waiting..
Battery voltage: 4.18 is charging: 0
Still dicharging the battery, waiting..
Battery voltage: 4.18 is charging: 0

It seems to trying to discharge it but keeps charging the battery? I've waited for about an hour and the voltage keeps staying at 4.18V and sometimes shows 4.17V but then goes back to showing 4.18V.
What could be going wrong? Thanks
EDIT: here is a picture of my circuit


Let us continue this discussion in chat.

hi jsotola i have attached the revised circuit in the chatroom, would you kindly take a look at it? Thanks

I have formatted your source, it was hardly readable. Please adopt a code style and stick to it.

hi i think you might've accidentally deleted the void loop from the code

No, I did not. Please use the scroll bar to view the other parts, the source view is height limited.

It probably has nothing to do with your code but the characteristics of your battery. What kind of battery you are using? Does your battery has the built-in over-charge and under-voltage protection circuit? What kind of charge you are using (does it has the protection for over-charge?). The battery may cut off at approximitely 4.2v but not quite 4.2v based on the over-charge protection threshold, and for the battery with under-voltage protection, depend on the IC, the cut-off might be at 2.3v instead of the 2.0v you are trying to do...

I do not think it is connected to the battery characteristics as you say because I tested it with a commercial battery charger that charges and discharges the battery to the same voltage numbers and it was able to do that fine.

From what you described, it further proof that your code work as it is supposed to do. isn't it? So you are using a "non-commercial" charger in this test, maybe you should look into this charger instead.

Hi I can't use the commercial charger because it only does it for a fixed number of cycles. I need it to go through 30 cycles which I why I am building this machine.
